# Does energy conserve in de Sitter Universe?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, universe, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

In the de Sitter's Universe with dark energy $p=-\rho= \mathrm{const}$ it seems the total energy of the Universe does not conserved, because $E=\rho V$, and $V$ is growing with time. Am I wrong?

PS

I think I found answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/33406/690

> The total energy in the space does increase

Comment: Energy is not conserved, but stress-energy is.

Comment: @bapowell I don't know anything about of energy density conservtion  and stress-energy conservtion. I heard only about total energy conservation in physics.

Comment: In general relativity, gravity is sourced by energy, momentum, pressure, and shear stress, versus only mass in Newtonian gravity. These quantities are packaged together into a 4x4 matrix called the stress-energy tensor. It acts as the source of gravity (also a tensor I quantity) in the Einstein field equations. In general relativity, it is this quantity— the stress-energy tensor — that is conserved.

Comment: @bapowell But in GR  in general case there is no conservation of energy in form of  derivative  stress-energy tensor, because Einstein equation  leads to zero covariant derivative  of stress-energy tensor, but not ordinary derivative  of stress-energy tensor.

Comment: That’s right. The conservation is with respect to the covariant derivative.

Comment: @bapowell perhaps I should pose a real Q. However, what in LamdaCDM is asserted about energy conservation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Since LCDM is a cosmological model based on general relativity, it exhibits the same conservation principles as GR; namely, that stress-energy -- not energy -- is conserved.  Because $\ddot{a} > 0$ in LCDM, we must have $\rho$ scaling with expansion no faster than $\rho \sim a^{-2}$, which means that the energy in a comoving volume grows.

Answer (score 1):

De Sitter space without matter admits multiple parameterizations which offer different answers to your question.

We define energy in context of GR by slicing spacetime into spacelike hypersurfaces (for example by fixing $t=t_0$) and integrating projection of stress-energy tensor over such slices. So to discuss energy (non)conservation you need to provide a recipe for this slicing.

Sometimes, this is done implicitly when there is a preferred slicing of spacetime. For example, if we have FLRW metric with matter that do not allow larger group of isometries (then each slice is an isotropic and uniform space) or if there is a global timelike Killing vector field (then we could define global time coordinate $t$).

However, de Sitter space as the one with maximal number of symmetries admits several choices for space slicing, some of which are listed at [its wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space).

First example: in **static coordinates** $\partial_t$ is a timelike Killing vector (not a global one, this parametrization has cosmological horizon) and so the energy (as integrated over the slice $t=\mathrm{const}$ within horizon) would be conserved. This would be preferred reference frame for a single galaxy after inflation has removed all the other galaxies beyond the horizon.

Second example: **flat slicing**. Total energy is obviously diverging, but if at $t=0$ we place observers on a nodes of cubic grid, with time as the space expands energy per one observer grows exponentially. This setting is usually implied by FLRW treatment of de Sitter space.

Other possibilities include exponentially decreasing energy and energy decreasing toward some minimum and then growing.