# Inflation and dark energy have constant energy density - energy is created out of nothing without any source or mechanism?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, cosmological-inflation, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

I can understand that a photon in an expanding universe can be redshifted and lose its energy by its wavelength being stretched from space expansion.

But in the case of inflation and dark energy, it doesn’t dilute/decrease with the expansion so that means more energy is created to keep energy density constant.

Doesn’t it need to have a mechanism of creating energy?  Or do we think that energy can be created out of nothing without any source or mechanism, like just a spontaneous increase in energy?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33404/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The simple answer is that energy is not conserved in general relativity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is dark energy consistent with conservation of mass and energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33404/how-is-dark-energy-consistent-with-conservation-of-mass-and-energy)